# How many different functions exist to scroll a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have been trying to find a function that is causing a certain webpage to scroll when I hover an element. I tried asking this question in a different way before, but got nowhere with the only proposed answer of someone teaching me how to create a function that scrolls a page - something that was absolutely unrelated to my question.

So now I am trying to ask this in a different way. These are all the scroll functions/methods (and/or related to scroll) that I know of:

```
[
    'scroll',
    'scrollTo',
    'scrollBy',
    'scrollByLines',
    'scrollByPages',
    'scrollX',
    'scrollY',
    'scrollMaxX',
    'scrollMaxY',
    'scrollHeight',
    'scrollIntoView',
    'scrollTop',
    'scrollTopMax'
].forEach(function(a) {
    console.log(window[a], document.documentElement[a]);
})
```

So now I am trying to find if there are any other scroll functions/methods that I am missing here, if you know of any (one or more) please tell me and hopefully the one(s) I am missing is the one causing the page I am studying to scroll.

Additional info: I already tried debugging, but the page contains lots of minified scripts, some reaching 15,000 lines of code, making this an almost impossible task.

I also tried checking the listeners (mouse over included) attached to the elements, but there are so many and each one leads to even more functions, all more intricated and more extensive.

It really is something scrolling the webpage, confirmed it on 3 different browsers (IE11, Firefox, Chrome), all responded with a scroll event being fired after adding `scroll` event listener and hovering the element.

I tried making all the above mentioned functions equal to `null` as an attempt to check for errors/seeing when the page would no longer scroll, but no luck.

Comment: I assume you've looked at the event listeners for that element. No joy there?

Comment: Try disabling scripts one by one until it no longer scrolls.

Comment: @isherwood Yep, no joy, but I just remembered one of the first things I've learned in javascript that is the answer to all of this, the culprit is the `.focus()` function.

Comment: @user694733 That was one of the first things I tried, but didn't work and no surprise there because the other scroll function missing was the `.focus()`, which isn't really scroll as the other ones, but it creates the same result when using it on an element outside the browser viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 days of trying to find this mysterious function it came to me after posting this question a second time, the function that is causing the page to scroll ended up being the `.focus()` function. I remembered it from a long time ago, but since I never used it ever since I learned about it and it isn't easy to relate to all the other scroll functions, it was giving me a hard time.

Thank you all that tried to pitch in with this. Hopefully someone else in the future will find this useful.